# Use `equation` environment inside `cutout` environment

Tags: equations, baposter, cutwin

this is the first time I ask something about Latex, so I am not sure about the conventions of when to include pictures and how to best create a MWE. Please tell me if I should provide more/less details to make my question clearer.

**Core Problem**

I want to wrap text which also includes an equation around a figure using the `cutout` environment of the `cutwin` package. The typesetting works just fine without the equation but as soon as I insert an `equation` environment the typesetting goes wild.
To be precise, the following code with the equation commented out is working fine (sorry for not using `\lipsum` directly, but this created different problems for some reason)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \opencutleft
    \begin{cutout}{5}{0pt}{0.5\textwidth}{10}
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
       vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
       tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metu
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
       %\begin{equation*}
       %   a+b=c
       %\end{equation*}
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
       vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
       tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metu
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    \end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

But with the equation disaster strucks (as shown in the picture).
This or a similar problem also occurs in all the other math environments (except in-line math) I have tried (like `align`, `$$`, `gather`, etc.).
As I have no idea how the placing inside these environments actually works, I am clueless how I should tackle this problem.
I would be grateful for any idea to solve this problem!
[image]

**More context**

As this behaviour can be seen in an `article` and outside any other environments, I believe the problem is with the combination of `cutout` and `equation`.
However, my actual example is still a bit more complicated, since I use the `baposter` document class (which can be downloaded [here](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)) with a `headerbox`. This is also the reason I use `cutout` and not `wrapfig`, since the latter seems completely incompatible with the other environments. So my actual MWE looks more like:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
grid=false,
headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=green, % Border color
headerColorOne=green, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=green, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=rounded, %rectangle, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.15\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headershade=plain,
headerfont=\Large\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt, % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}{}{}{}{}
\headerbox{Test}{name=test, column=0, row=0, span=2}{
    \opencutleft
    \begin{cutout}{5}{0pt}{0.5\textwidth}{10}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
    bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
    tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metu
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
    bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec%
    \begin{equation*}
         a+b=c
    \end{equation*}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
    bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
    tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metu
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
    bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    \end{cutout}
}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

I know it is probably unnecessary, but I left in my poster settings, since I don't know which setting might be relevant for the problem.

So to summarize, I am looking for a way to combine the `headerbox` environment with something that can wrap text with an equation around a figure and I would be really grateful if someon could provide me with some ideas, since I am really out of my depth here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give cutwin  a bit of help by hiding the equation in a minipage of the right width

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \opencutleft
    \begin{cutout}{5}{0pt}{0.5\textwidth}{10}
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
       vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
       tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metu
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec\\
       \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
       \begin{equation*}
          a+b=c
       \end{equation*}         
       \end{minipage}\\
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
       vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
       tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metu
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vesti-
       bulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
       Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
    \end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may also want to add a bit of vertical space at the start or end of the `minipage`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was sure I tried this at some point but apparently I messed something up, so thanks!
Just one quick follow up question: If my equation contains a fraction or any other "big" symbol like an Integral, there is a super ugly whitespace in the text one line before the end of the cutout. I guess this has something to do with the way `cutout` counts the lines of the cutout. Do you have any idea how to circumvent this?

Comment: I also just noticed that I have trouble inserting the `\vspace`s as you suggested to properly place the equation. As soon as I insert them the same problem as with the fractions arises.

Comment: @K'azzD'Avore `\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{equation*}a+b=c\end{equation*}\vspace*{10pt}\end{minipage}` should work